# Google app engine demo app jsp page creates 500 error

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Hello I am trying out Google app engine and eclipse. I ihave installed the google plug in and have copied the code in the demo exactly.  I saw a similar question posted here and I tried the solution of making sure the JDK was checked instead of JRE. I am using the guestbook demo for java and when I get to the part where  I add the jsp page I am still getting this error :

HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /. Reason:

```
Error running javac.exe compiler
```

Caused by:
Error running javac.exe compiler
 at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.DefaultCompilerAdapter.executeExternalCompile(DefaultCompilerAdapter.java:509)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.JavacExternal.execute(JavacExternal.java:61)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1065)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:882)
 at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:382)
 at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:472)
 at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:451)
 at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:439)
 at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:511)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:295)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:292)

Answer (score 0):

You may have run the ant target before switching JRE to JDK so the launch configuration is old and refers to the JRE which doesn't have a javac.exe.

Try opening the launch configuration (by selecting the Run As... menu entry - the dots are important), and verify that *this* Java Runtime points to the JDK also.  This should fix it.  Also verify that you actually have switched the JRE correctly for all of Eclipse in the Preferences.

Comment: Ok, I have now switched all the jre preferences.  I do not have an option for run as because when I select run as I get a greyed out option that says 1 XSL Transformation.